# React: State value becomes undefined in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Can't figure out what is going on here (using an image because it's clearer to explain).

On highlighted line #114, `movesAry` is undefined. Initially, all breakpoints (outside of the one highlighted, which is not executed initially) show it as an empty array. However, when `selecteDb` changes and `useEffect()` is triggered for the first time, the `movesAry` value has become undefined. Note that no call to `setMovesAry()` has been made yet. Subsequent breakpoints now also show that `movesAry` is undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is that, on line 120, arrSeg gets assigned an object such that `arrSeg.value` is undefined. Then you call `setMovesAry(arrSeg.value)`, which causes movesAry to be undefined

Comment: Andre: except that useEffect() is only called for the first time after selectedDb has changed, so line #120 has never been executed up until that point.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up breaking down the component into smaller ones, ending up with a `MoveRows` component that gets the `movesAry` state via props. So now in my `useEffect` function I am able to `setMovesAry` without it blowing away the `movesAry` state.

```
const MoveRows = ({ selectedDb, setMovesAry, movesAry }) => {
    const { db } = selectedDb
    const doMore = () => {
        const arrSeg = addMoves({ db }).next()
        if (!arrSeg.done) setMovesAry(prev => prev.concat(arrSeg.value))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (db) {
            setMovesAry([])
            doMore()
        }
    }, [selectedDb])
   ...
```

I also got rid of the `pojos` ref by merging it into the `selectedDb` structure. Everything seems to work now, so I'll mark this as the answer.